# C# - Fastest way to do this type of null check?

Tags: c#, performance, expression

I have the following code that performs a null or empty check on any type of object:

```
  public static void IfNullOrEmpty(Expression<Func<string>> parameter)
  {
     Throw.IfNull(parameter);
     if (parameter.GetValue().ToString().Length == 0)
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot be empty", parameter.GetName());
     }
  }
```

It calls the GetValue extension method below:

```
  public static T GetValue<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> parameter)
  {
     MemberExpression member;
     Expression expression;

     member = (MemberExpression)parameter.Body;
     expression = member.Expression;

     return (T)parameter.Compile()();
  }
```

I am passing in an expression containing a string in this method for testing. This method takes on average 2 ms on my machine (even slower on another machine I'm testing on) which adds up if it is called several times throughout the application. It seems like this method is too slow. What is the fastest way to do this type of null check?

Comment: You're probably timing the JIT. They should have a huge warning in VS for newbies not to try to time anything, they'll always do it wrong.

Comment: When I profile the application as a whole I see similar results as if I just timed that code individually.

Comment: Why are you using an expression anyway? Why not just `Func<T>`?

Comment: @Andrew, because you're reading it just as wrong. The "inclusive time" column is a lot more literal than you think.

Comment: @Blindy - Yes, he's also timing the JIT, which is correct since the JIT is also being invoked every call to `Compile`. His reading is correct, calling `Expression.Compile()` is simply expensive *because* it does invoke the JIT (and other reasons).

Comment: It's also compiling the function itself, and only once.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling an expression naturally requires quite some work. What I normally do if this code will run often is that I only compile the expressions once and save the compiled delegate for further usage.

It's possible to keep a "normal" cache but for a cache to be efficient you need a good hash function and I don't see how you could make that here. You need to restructure your code a bit so that every place where you use GetValue has a proper access to a compiled delegate instead. Without seeing more code I can't give you any hints about that one.

There can be many reasons why you see the following call being faster. Because of the difficulty to hash I don't expect that one. More likely you are seeing the works of a modern CPU that does a lot of guessing to run code fast. If you just ran the same expressions it's possible that the CPU is able to to guess more about the next call and can run faster. There is always GC to consider too.

One way to test the guessing idea could be to create a large array with a few different expressions. Do one test where it is ordered by expression and one where it is random. If my suspicion holds true the first one should be faster.

Comment: How do you save the compiled delegate? Would I be able to reuse the same delegate for any type of string or object passed in?

Comment: Perhaps put your equation in a class.  When you store a value into it the cache is marked as invalid.  When you attempt to read the result and it's invalid you recalculate it.

Comment: @Andrew If you can share some code where you use this method I might be able to suggest a solution. There are a few ways but none is trivial enough to fit every case.

Comment: Here is an example of how I call the method: string clientId = "Test"; Throw.IfNullOrEmpty(() => clientId);

Comment: Then I think you might be out of luck because for these "ad hoc" calls there is no easy way to cache them without complicating the code.

If you care about the perf I'm afraid you have to change to a more manual way. I use "nameof" in c# 6. A little more code though.

```Ensure.That(request.CompanyId, nameof(request.CompanyId)).IsNotEmpty();```

Comment: Ensure is a library called EnsureThat I'm using

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right, the only reason why you need an `Expression` is so if the check fails, you'll be able to extract the name of the parameter and pass it into the exception that you'll throw, right? If so, that's an awfully steep price to pay for a slightly more convenient error message that (hopefully) only occurs in a very tiny percentage of cases.

The 2ms overhead is slightly higher than I'd expect, but substantial overhead is hard or impossible to avoid here. You're essentially forcing the runtime to traverse an expression tree, translate it into MSIL and then translate and optimize that MSIL again into executable code through the JIT, just to do a `!= null` check which will always succeed unless a developer has made a mistake somewhere.

You could probably come up with some sort of caching mechanism; the Entity Framework caches expressions by traversing the expression tree and building a hash of it and uses that as the key of a dictionary where the compiled expression is stored as a delegate. It'd be substantially cheaper than sending it through the JIT on every call, but it'd still be orders of magnitude more expensive when compared to a simpler `!= null` check which takes nanoseconds or less (especially when you consider modern branch-predicting CPUs).

So in my opinion, this approach is a nice idea, but simply not worth it when you  consider the cost and when the alternative is pretty painless (especially with the new `nameof` operator). It's also fairly brittle, because what if I'm a developer who thinks he can do this:

`Throw.IfNullOrEmpty(() => clientId + "something")`

Your cast to `MemberExpression` will fail there.

Likewise, it would be reasonable for someone to think that *because* you pass in an expression and an expression is only code as data that it would be safe to do this:

`Throw.IfNullOrEmpty(() => parent.Child.MightBeNull.MightAlsoBeNull.ClientID)`

It's perfectly possible to safely evaluate that expression if you partially traversed the expression tree, but in your example the whole expression is compiled and executed at once and will likely fail with a `NullReferenceException` there.

I guess it comes down to that an argument of type `Expression<Func<T>>` is just not sufficiently strict enough for the use of a null check. You could do all sorts of weird stuff in them and the compiler would be perfectly happy, but you'd get unexpected results at runtime.